# Flutter - Failed to build IOS App using Android Studio on mac

Tags: flutter

I was trying to use audioplayers package in my small project in Flutter and I ended having this error for some weeks now

```
    **Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMediaPlayer'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility51'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility50'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUniformTypeIdentifiers'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
    ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "nominal type descriptor for Foundation.NSKeyValueObservation", referenced from:
          _symbolic _____Sg 10Foundation21NSKeyValueObservationC in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "type metadata accessor for Foundation.Notification", referenced from:
          reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Foundation.Notification) -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSNotification) -> () in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "static Foundation.Notification._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(__C.NSNotification?) -> Foundation.Notification", referenced from:
          reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Foundation.Notification) -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) (@unowned __C.NSNotification) -> () in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "Foundation.URL._bridgeToObjectiveC() -> __C.NSURL", referenced from:
          @nonobjc __C.AVPlayerItem.init(url: Foundation.URL) -> __C.AVPlayerItem in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "Foundation.URL.init(fileURLWithPath: __shared Swift.String) -> Foundation.URL", referenced from:
          audioplayers.WrappedMediaPlayer.setUrl(url: Swift.String, isLocal: Swift.Bool, isNotification: Swift.Bool, recordingActive: Swift.Bool, onReady: (__C.AVPlayer) -> ()) -> () in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "Swift.Array.append(__owned A) -> ()", referenced from:
          audioplayers.WrappedMediaPlayer.setUrl(url: Swift.String, isLocal: Swift.Bool, isNotification: Swift.Bool, recordingActive: Swift.Bool, onReady: (__C.AVPlayer) -> ()) -> () in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
      "_swift_getKeyPath", referenced from:
          audioplayers.WrappedMediaPlayer.setUrl(url: Swift.String, isLocal: Swift.Bool, isNotification: Swift.Bool, recordingActive: Swift.Bool, onReady: (__C.AVPlayer) -> ()) -> () in libaudioplayers.a(WrappedMediaPlayer.o)
```

It is quite a long output. I have tried all the found solutions and it is not working.I tried to run flutter doctor but everything was right. Here is the updated error

Comment: Dude you can remove this `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` and run this `cd ios` after `pod install`

Comment: It has updated pod but now I have a new error

Comment: Okay pls upload new error i’ll check it

Comment: I have already updated thank you

Comment: Look, you should remove `ios/Pods`, `Podfile.lock` and `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework`. After you have to run this: `cd ios` `pod install`

Comment: It saying [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: First go into ios folder, with using this - `cd ios` after do other methods

Comment: That what I did actually